# How to create a Form dynamically?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I want to create, dynamically, forms depending a type of user. For example:
I want, if it is an administrator, to create the form or the buttons, for this user specifically.
 In the code of my login there is a validation that identifies the type of user.
But I only did that when it identifies the user to send it to the corresponding screen with its buttons already set, but what I want is that when identifying the user type, generate the buttons that the user should have access to;
The user has a type of user and that type of user has 1 or more permissions, then, depending on how many permissions that user has, create the buttons. Each permission is a button.
Example:
The user Alfonso is type of sales and has permissions to invoice and sell, then when it initiates session the "invoice" and "sell" buttons will be generated.

Comment: winforms are dynamically created.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a "UserType" table:

   ```
   |   id   |   userType      |
   |--------------------------|
   |   1    |   Administrator |
   |   2    |   Sales         |
   ```
2. Create a "Menu" or "options" table:

   ```
   |   id   |   option   |
   |---------------------|
   |   1    |   Invoice  |
   |   2    |   Sell     |
   ```
3. Create a Permissions by user type Table(with the list of options)

   ```
   |   idUserType   |   idOption   |  allow   |
   |----------------|--------------|----------|
   |         2      |        1     |  true    |
   |         2      |        2     |  true    |
   ```
4. Create ALL the options in your aplication [dynamical] (create the buttons with the options from the database)
5. When Login get all the permissions for the user type
6. Change the visible attribute to false for all the buttons, except the ones on the Permissions by user type Table

Thats my idea, all configurable from the DataBase

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to create classes that inherit from `Form`, and add the controls you want and set the properties of the controls to what you want.  When you need a form you just create a `new` one.  If necessary you can pass parameters you need in setting up the form through the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Below is just an example to show how to open different Form based on user type. You can optimize it further when you redesign it as per your requirement.
In below code assumption is `FUser1` and `FUser2` are 2 forms to be opened as per the `userType` variable.

```
private FUser1 fUser1;
private FUser2 fUser2;
private FUser2 fUserAdmin;

private void OpenForm(int userType)
{
    switch (userType)
    {
        case 1:
            if (fUser1 == null)
            {
                fUser1 = new FUser1();
                //do initialization specific to FUser1
                fUser1.txtLogin.Text = "Robinhood";
            }
            fUser1.Show();
            break;
        case 2:
            if (fUser2 == null)
            {
                fUser2 = new FUser2();
                //do initialization specific to FUser2
                fUser2.btnProcess.Enable = false;
                fUser2.btnPermit.Visible = false;               
            }
            fUser2.Show();
            break;
        case 3: //Admin
            if (fUserAdmin == null)
            {
                fUserAdmin = new FUser2();
                //do initialization specific to FUser2
                fUserAdmin.btnProcess.Enable = true;
                fUserAdmin.btnPermit.Visible = true;
                fUserAdmin.ProcessSales(); //Public function in FUser2
            }
            fUserAdmin.Show();
            break;
    }         
}
```